# Column number of supplied values does not mach table definition - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou com o seguinte problema no sql server quando coloco a cláusula CASE no final dessa linha de código:

```
DECLARE @RESULTADO TABLE (
Total INT,
GrupoTitulo VARCHAR(255),
GrupoChave VARCHAR(255),
GrupoNome VARCHAR(255),
GrupoOrdem VARCHAR(255),
ProdGrupo VARCHAR(255),
ProdGrupoOrdem INT,
ProdCodEstr VARCHAR(40),
ProdCodRed VARCHAR(7),
ProdNome VARCHAR(80),
ProdUnidMedCod VARCHAR(7),
ProdUnidMedPos SMALLINT,
ValTotVendasFinal NUMERIC(14,2),
ValTotVendasIPI NUMERIC(14,2),
ValTotVendas NUMERIC(14,2),
ValTotDevolucoes NUMERIC(14,2),
QtdVendas NUMERIC(24,9),
QtdDevolucoes NUMERIC(24,9),

------
ValTotVendasFinalFD NUMERIC(14,2),
ValTotVendasIPIFD NUMERIC(14,2),
ValTotVendasFD NUMERIC(14,2),
ValTotDevolucoesFD NUMERIC(14,2),
QtdVendasFD NUMERIC(24,9),
QtdDevolucoesFD NUMERIC(24,9)
)


 INSERT INTO @RESULTADO
 SELECT
0,
CAST (CASE
    WHEN '' = 'CIDADE' THEN 'Cidade'
    WHEN '' = 'ESTADO' THEN 'Estado'
    WHEN '' = 'CLIENTE' THEN 'Cliente'
    WHEN '' = 'GRUPO' THEN 'Grupo de Produtos'
    WHEN '' = 'VENDEDOR' THEN 'Vendedor'
    WHEN '' = 'CATEGORIA' THEN 'Categoria'
END AS VARCHAR(255)) GrupoTitulo,
ISNULL(V.GrupoChave,D.GrupoChave) GrupoChave,
ISNULL(V.GrupoNome,D.GrupoNome) GrupoNome,
ISNULL(V.GrupoOrdem, D.GrupoOrdem),
CAST(CASE
    WHEN P.ProdCodEstr LIKE '07%'    THEN 'Fralda'
    WHEN P.ProdCodEstr LIKE '30.03%' THEN 'Bobina'
    WHEN P.ProdCodEstr LIKE '30%'    THEN 'Tissue'
    ELSE 'Outros'
END AS VARCHAR(255)) ProdGrupo,
    CASE
    WHEN P.ProdCodEstr LIKE '07%'    THEN 2
    WHEN P.ProdCodEstr LIKE '30.03%' THEN 3
    WHEN P.ProdCodEstr LIKE '30%'    THEN 1
    ELSE 4
END ProdGrupoOrdem,
P.ProdCodEstr, P.ProdCodRed, P.ProdNome,
UPPER(ISNULL(V.ProdUnidMedCod, D.ProdUnidMedCod)) ProdUnidMedCod,
ISNULL(V.ProdUnidMedPos, D.ProdUnidMedPos) ProdUnidMedPos,

V.ItNFValTotFinal ValTotVendasFinal,
V.ItNFValIpi ValTotVendasIPI,
(V.ItNFValTotFinal - V.ItNFValIpi) ValTotVendas,

D.ItNFValTotFinal ValTotDevolucoes,
V.ItNFQtd QtdVendas, D.ItNFQtd QtdDevolucoes,

-- O ERRO DÁ A PARTIR DAQUI - QUANDO EU INSIRO ESTAS CONDIÇÕES:
```

Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

```
  CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(V.ProdUnidMedCod, D.ProdUnidMedCod)) = 'FD' THEN 
  V.ItNFValTotFinal ELSE 0 END ValTotVendasFinalFD,
  CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(V.ProdUnidMedCod, D.ProdUnidMedCod)) = 'FD' THEN 
  V.ItNFValIpi ELSE 0 END ValTotVendasIPIFD,
  CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(V.ProdUnidMedCod, D.ProdUnidMedCod)) = 'FD' THEN 
  (V.ItNFValTotFinal - V.ItNFValIpi) ELSE 0 END ValTotVendasFD,

  CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(V.ProdUnidMedCod, D.ProdUnidMedCod)) = 'FD' THEN 
  D.ItNFValTotFinal ELSE 0 END ValTotDevolucoesFD,
  CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(V.ProdUnidMedCod, D.ProdUnidMedCod)) = 'FD' THEN 
  V.ItNFQtd ELSE 0 END QtdVendasFD,
  CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(V.ProdUnidMedCod, D.ProdUnidMedCod)) = 'FD' THEN 
  D.ItNFQtd ELSE 0 END QtdDevolucoesFD
```

Comment: A mensagem é bem objetiva, você está informando um número diferente de colunas do que `@RESULTADO` possui. Como você fez o `insert` sem definir os campos, precisa passar valores **para todos os campos, na ordem que eles estão na tabela**, verifique o comando pra ver o q está faltando ou a mais

Comment: Inclusive seguindo o comentário do @RicardoPontual, o ideal é que você defina os campos no `INSERT` pra garantir que adição de campos não vai quebrar o código

Comment: Eu já fiz isso e não deu certo

Comment: O que o @Sorack comentou é muito importante, além de garantir que não vai quebrar o comando caso a tabela mude, já daria pra até te ajudar dizendo se tem colunas a mais ou menos no comando.

Comment: Faz isso e edita a pergunta, assim, como o @RicardoPontual comentou dá pra vermos quais colunas podem estar sobrando

Comment: Bom é só você contar os campos da tabela e ver se os values está corretos. Pode ser também um problema de vírgula ou aspas que tenham em algum campo, isso já aconteceu comigo e acabou quebrando o valor de um campo em 2

Comment: Já arrumei o código. Era alguns INSERTS que eu estava fazendo depois daquelas linhas ali, o valor não estava saindo correto